# How to make swf file in full screen after clicking the button and again clicking it want to display in default size

Tags: javascript, html

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head><title>Video Resize</title></head>
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
<button onclick="previous()"> << </button>
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 

  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="next()"> >> </button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="320" >
<source src="gizmo.mp4" type="video/mp4" border="10">
 <source src="test1.swf" type="swf" border="10">
  </video>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig()
{ 
myVideo.width=1000; 
} 

function makeSmall()
{ 
myVideo.width=320; 
} 

function makeNormal()
{ 
myVideo.width=480; 
} 

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

How to make .swf file in full screen after clicking the button and again clicking it want to display in default size.For ex: if I click big, the swf file want to display in full screen.If I click normal means it want to display in normal size.If I click default it want to display in default size.kindly give me the solution for my above mentioned problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its possible only with actionscript 
Refer:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html

Note:
You need to add the button inside your swf file